# Trying to run a compile command while saving post

Tags: hooks

I have a front end built with Gatsby, connecting to WordPress via the REST API.

Each time I update a post, I need run a command to compile. Below is my attempt at automating this using the save_post filter function:

```
<?php

function li_rebuild_gatsby( $id, $post, $update ) {
    $command_one = "cd /home/web/public/website425.com";
    $command_two = "gatsby build";
    @exec( $command_one . "&& " . $command_two );
}
add_filter( 'save_post' , 'li_rebuild_gatsby' , 10, 3 );
```

It seems I need to change into a sudo'er and supply a password.

What is the right way to run this command?

Comment: Another workaround to avoid the exec in PHP is e.g. to modify a file instead on updates and check the modified file time via Linux cron if the build should run

Comment: Another question that arises is if you really want to do a rebuild of the frontend on _every save_, you should check the post status first, there is no gain in trigger a rebuild for saving drafts.